# How should I log in ruby with minimum assumptions about the calling code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging

In java/jvm, we have slf4j which can be included without making any assumptions about the logging implementation. How can I achieve something similar in a ruby library/gem?

Comment: Does console log using `puts` not serve your purpose? Is there some additional behavior other than logging to STDOUT that you are after?

Comment: To draw a parallel from my java experience, a library author would use slf4j and will leave the decision of a logging implementation on its calling code. I dont see `puts` at the same abstract level. Some calling code may not want to see any logs in `puts/stdout` rather they may wish to collect all logs into a file. They may also want to collect some logs in file, while others on a console. All this flexibility is not provided by using an implementation like `puts`

See a description of slf4j/java here:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/145079/45536

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a pretty common pattern in various ruby logger implementations to mimic the method interface of the standards library [Logger](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html), namely

- the logger object responds to the methods `debug`, `info`,  `warn`, `error`, `fatal` where you can pass a string containing the log message. Many logger implementations also allow to pass a block (which returns the log message) rather than an actual string
- You also generally have an `add` method where you can pass a numeric log severity and the log message.

In your code, you can generally expect that all logger implementations implement at least this interface. You can then allow users of your code to provide their own `logger` object (which should implement those methods) which you can then use. This pattern is called [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)

Generally, in Ruby, you don't care about actual types of a given object. You just assume that is responds to messages send to it ("methods called"). As such, you don't need to care about a specific logger implementation, but just that it implements the expected interface. In Ruby, this is often called [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).

Comment: can you show an example? Should I include Logger library and use it (like it is in jvm/slf4j) - i doubt it? or does the Logger's instance has to be taken as a parameter?  What is the recommended pattern for ruby library code?

Comment: An example would be the Rails logger. By default, Rails sets up a logger which logs to a file. But you (as in: the author of a Rails application) [can also define your own custom logger](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#the-logger). If your library has no sensible default way to log, you may alternatively require the calling code (i.e. the user of your library) to always provide a suitable logger object, e.g. to your class's `initialize` method. There are multiple options here which strongly depend on your specific library and its architecture.